# Logging errors to a file

Tags: python

I have a log file on one of the servers and I need to write a python script to copy the lines that contain ERROR and INFO tags. I want all the lines with the tags to be written to a new file every time I run the script.

Here is what I have written so far ( I am a newbie )

```
my_errors=open("/var/tmp/myerrors1.txt", "w")
my_trace=open("/var/tmp/logs/trace1.txt", "r")
my_trace.readline()

x = [INFO, WARN, ERRor]

for line in  my_trace:
    for x in line:
         my_errors.writelines(x)

my_errors.close()
my_trace.close()
```

trace1.txt example:

```
03/17/2015 13:41:55|WARN||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-5|495233559||_ERR: execute(): Error Response returned 
03/17/2015 13:41:47|INFO||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-2|495785359||_IN:SearchQuery getList(): ||||
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_errors = open("/var/tmp/myerrors1.txt", "w")
my_trace = open("/var/tmp/logs/trace1.txt", "r")

levels = ['INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR']

for line in my_trace:
    if any(level in line for level in levels):
        my_errors.write(line)

my_errors.close()
my_trace.close()
```

Tested using the following `trace1.txt` file:

```
03/17/2015 13:41:55|WARN||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-5|495233559||_ERR: execute(): Error Response returned 
Do not copy this line
03/17/2015 13:41:47|INFO||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-2|495785359||_IN:SearchQuery getList(): ||||
Do not copy this line
```

Result of `myerrors1.txt` file:

```
03/17/2015 13:41:55|WARN||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-5|495233559||_ERR: execute(): Error Response returned 
03/17/2015 13:41:47|INFO||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-2|495785359||_IN:SearchQuery getList(): ||||
```

Edit 2:

```
my_errors = open("/var/tmp/myerrors1.txt", "w")
my_trace = open("/var/tmp/logs/trace1.txt", "r")

levels = ['INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR']

for line in my_trace:
    for level in levels:
        if level in line:
            my_errors.write(line)    

my_errors.close()
my_trace.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try your solution and will update.

Comment: I tried the above solution but the problem I see is that the entire trace1.txt is being copied to myerrors1.txt, instead of copying the lines that contain items from the levels list.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your `trace1.txt` file?

Comment: 03/17/2015 13:41:55|WARN||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-5|495233559||_ERR: execute(): Error Response returned                          03/17/2015 13:41:47|INFO||ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-4090-exec-2|495785359||_IN:SearchQuery getList():  ||||

Comment: I'm not getting the same issue. Can you try testing it with the contents of `trace1.txt` I used in my solution?

Comment: Thanks! for trying, will do it now.

Comment: What I did is, I wanted to capture the lines with the WARN and ERROR tags but I get the lines with INFO tags as well. I tried this                                                                        my_errors = open("/var/tmp/myerrors1.txt", "w")
my_trace = open("/var/tmp/logs/trace1.txt", "r")

levels = [ 'WARN', 'ERROR']

for line in my_trace:
    if any(level in line for level in levels):
        my_errors.write(line)

my_errors.close()
my_trace.close()

Comment: I have tested your version of my solution and am still not able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Did you try the code with levels = ['WARN', 'ERROR'] and it filtered on WARN and ERROR tags. In my case I got the line with INFO tag as well.

Comment: Yes. I correctly get the lines that have WARN and ERROR in them. None of the lines containing INFO get copied over for me.

Comment: Thanks! a lot for your time. I get the lines with INFO as well. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: I my case with the if statement, I didn't use any(). When I use if any(level in line for level in levels) I get the following error. I think any() function is new in 2.5 version                                                                                         File "error_parser.py", line 8, in ?
 if any(level in line for level in levels):
NameError: name 'any' is not defined

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: This is the version Python 2.4.3

Comment: It worked. I really appreciate your help. You are a great resource. Can you suggest me a few sites where I can practice and learn Python. Thanks! again for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is a great way to learn and practice Python.

Comment: Done.  Accepted the answer. Please list any other sites apart from the one that you suggested( I learnt the basics from codeacademy).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a question, but I think that your issue is that nothing is writing to your file. You are reassigning `x` to something else (the values in `line`). You need to assign it a different variable, like so:

```
my_errors=open("/var/tmp/myerrors1.txt", "w")
my_trace=open("/var/tmp/logs/trace1.txt", "r")
my_trace.readline()

x = [INFO, WARN, ERRor]

for line in  my_trace:
    for message in line: # change from reassigning the x variable to something else
        for error in x: # iterating through the errors in x
            if error in my_trace: # checking if an error is in my_trace
                my_errors.writelines(error) # writing the error

my_errors.close()
my_trace.close()
```

Of course, without full information, it's not the best answer, but it should be something you can build upon to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks! for your reply.  Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I wanted to copy the lines from the trace file to a different, if a line contained any of the above mentioned log levels( info, warn or error).